# Strange Behaviour on changing the property of button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I am disabling a button on click handler and it is strange that once the button is disabled, it doesn't get submitted after that.
It varies from browser to browser. Firefox allows the submission of the form after disabling the submit button but chrome and IE are blocking it

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#btn").on("click",function(){

                $(this).prop('disabled','true');
                alert('clicked');
            });



            $("#frm").on("submit",function(){
                alert("submit1");

            });

            $("#frm").on("submit",function(){
                alert("submit2");
            });

        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="frm" action="#">
        <input type='submit' id="btn"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is a strange behavior that submit is being prevented on disabling the buttton.
what could be the probable reason.
output which i am getting in Chrome and IE are 
click is executed and then script close

why isnt it in order
execution of click
then execution of submits

Comment: change type="submit" to type="button"

Comment: @Riturajratan: Learner appears to *want* the form to be submitted.

Comment: Its not about changing the type from SUBMIT to button
Its about "WHY it is so "
It is a simple case which i have written , In our scenario we cant change the code as you are suggesting

Comment: I believe the issue is different browsers follow different execution cycles/decide different events occur and different times. I think merging your logic such that the disabling of the button happens after an explicit call to submit the form should solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're saying that when you disable the submit button as it is clicked, the form doesn't get submitted and you want it to.

I believe the *reason* for that is that the `click` event occurs before the button's *activation behavior* (which is the HTML5 spec's term for "what it does"). The activation behavior of an enabled ("mutable" as the spec puts it) submit button is, of course, to trigger form submission. But by the time the browser is deciding on the activation behavior, which is *after* the `click` handlers have been fired, you've disabled the button. According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#submit-button-state-%28type=submit%29), a disabled ("non-mutable" as they put it) submit button *has* no activation behavior, and so the form is not submitted.

So the question becomes: When does the browser decide what activation behavior to use, before the `click` handlers or after them? For the answer to that, we turn to the DOM Events spec, which tells us that [first the `click` occurs, *then* the activation behavior occurs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-activation-event-order). So it would appear that Chrome is deciding after the `click` event is complete, which is a reasonable read of the spec; Firefox would appear to be deciding *before* the `click` event is complete.

Pragmatically, though, the reality is that if you disable the button within the `click` handler, you are not guaranteed to get the form submission. To work around that, you can *very briefly* delay disabling the button, so the event completes without the button having been disabled:

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    var btn = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }, 0);
    alert('clicked');
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ahajoSI/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ahajoSI/1/edit)

---

Side note: In the above, I've also (effectively) replaced `$(this).prop("disabled", true");` with (effectively) `this.disabled = true;`. There's no reason to wrap the element in a jQuery wrapper just to set a simple property value.

Comment: Its not about the changing the code
I am want to know whats the reason blocking the submission as same is working good in firefox.
and regarding changes my code base is large and contains many handlers , I have put here just a simple example to create the issue

Comment: @Learner: I've added an explanation (and link) for why.

Comment: @Learner: And added even more. But the original answer was the pragmatic one: You just have to change that code, pain though it is.

Answer (score 1):

Should fix your issue:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true).closest('form').submit();
        //to submit FORM without firing jquery's attached handlers
        //$(this).prop('disabled', true).closest('form').get(0).submit();
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/REU9L/)

Comment: In this case all the event Handlers attached onsubmit of form by javascript[not juqery] will not be executed .But i want to execute all handlers attached to SUBMIT of form

Comment: Worth noting as well that if the submit button has a value, the above will not pass that value on with the form as a normal submission would.